# dynamically image slider using bootstrap carousal is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use and show dynamically image slider in asp.net but is not working. Bootstrap Slider is working on statically properly but when I coded dynamically don't gain output properly.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action ="add_photo.aspx">
    <div>
       <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
           <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>
           </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="item<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "" %>">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ='<%# 
                      Eval("path").ToString() %>'/>
                        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

**Code Behind-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    show_data();

}

private void show_data()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    con.Open();

    string query = "Select * from SliderImage";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: `It's not working` meaning it does not show any image or shows all images?

Comment: when I am using inspect then shows all the images but when I click on the next and previous button then show only active and first images

Comment: try to repeat `li` under `ol - carousel-indicators` same as you are repeating images.

Comment: all the images like 2-4 images store on the database and folder but slider doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't get your point sir. How can I use

Comment: You should to know, is rendered out put like static content ? it may be different than the static after rendering.

Comment: Yes sir, it's rendered output like static content but i have coded here dynamically. Can you tell me that any code error or mistake on my code snippet.

Comment: `<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic"></li>` this targets your image. Now all three are same and there are only three. So you need to repeat these with unique target (like `data-slide-to="your-image-id"`). BTW you have done right by giving `active` class to first image (first I suspected that).

Comment: Sir, I have tried and edited my code as you instruct me but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I know i am late, but please use !ispostback on page load .